# Sum variable range : replace indirect with non volatile

Tags: excel, volatile, sumifs, excel-indirect, vba

I use this formula a lot in my spreadsheet :

```
SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row(),column(B))&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH("*",INDIRECT("A"& row()+1&":A"& row()+250),0)+ row()-1,column(B))))
```

This works but there are several volatile functions in this formula. I want to clean this code and make it as fast as possible.

In column A I have names (apple, pear, strawberry, ...). In column B I have values. For a fruit I can have several values. But there is no name for values 2, 3, 4, ... Column A is empty for values 2,3,4,5, ...
I 'd like to do sum values for each name in column C.

How can I do that without volatile functions please ?

Thanks for your help :) !

Comment: Can you add a screenshot as well? :)

Comment: so if you were putting this in row 2 first it would be: `SUM(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*",A3:A252,0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner : That works for the first name but not for the next names :-(.

Vityata : A1 : apple, A2 :empty, A3 : empty, A4 pear, B1 to B4 : numbers, C1 : sum of numbers for apple (B1 to B3), C4 : number of pear : sum of B4:B4

Comment: @JohnDT please put the data in the Original Post using [edit].  it cannot be formatted in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the first row then copy down.

```
=IF(A1<>"",SUM(B1:B250)-SUM(C2:C252),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this idea but if I insert a row after row 1 (so, new row 2), the formula in C1 become : =IF(A1<>"",SUM(B1:B250)-SUM(C3:C253),"")
So, the formula is not okay anymore and there are risks if I modify the content (add a name in A2, add values, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a formula that seems to works and that is a fork of your first formula Scott :

```
=IF(A1="","",SUM(B1:INDEX(B1:B$10,MATCH("*",INDEX(A1:A$10,2,1):A$10,0),1)))
```

What do you think about it ?
Is it performant and fast, even when there are plenty cells with this formula (with index) ?